# What is the origin of state concept?

Tags: turing-machines, history, imperative-programming

On a [Turing machine](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/turing-machine/one.html#one-four), the state changes during the execution of the program. Von Neumann architecture implements this machine theory and typical computer hardware uses Von Neumann architecture.

Imperative programs [uses the state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science)#Program_state) to describes their computations.

Semantically, is correct to say that **imperative program works like a Turing machine**? If not, theoretically, what is the origin of state used by imperative programming?

Comment: "Von Neumann architecture implements this machine theory" -- nope. TMs *don't* have shared memory space for instructions and data. I don't think the two concepts are related; they happen to co-occur in modern machines, true (to the extent to which modern machines are Turing-equivalent).

Comment: "imperative program works like a Turing machine" -- maybe in the sense that horses run like sharks swim, but otherwise... not so much.

Comment: This is the second question of this kind in a short time. I recommend you do some more reading before trying to write a report. In particular, make sure you know your way around different models of computation.